# How to require manual 'Admin' approval of an OAuth application when using Doorkeeper?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, doorkeeper

Let's say we have `Users` (who can create `Doorkeeper::Application`s). On the other hand our app has `Admins` who ideally need to check each Application that is created (and maybe do a background check on the creating User and what not) as well as its scopes. They would `#approve!` or `#reject!` the Application and only once it is `approved`, can the Application make calls to the API.

**NOTE**: `#approve!`, `#reject!`, and `approved` do not come with Doorkeeper, from what I know. They are hypothetical so my question is clearer.

Is this a behavior that can be achieved with Doorkeeper (or an extension)? I don't think something like this is described in the config file. If not, do you have any general steps on how this could be done?

I'm thinking that something like this could work

```rb
class Api::V1::TransactionalBaseController < Api::V1::AuthableController
  before_action :doorkeeper_authorize!
  before_action :check_application_status!

  private
  def check_application_status!
    application = doorkeeper_token.application
    unless application.approved?
      raise Doorkeeper::Errors::ApplicationForbidden.new
    end
  end
end
```

If this is something that may help other users of the gem, I'm open to possibly opening a PR or developing an extension to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

`rails g migration AddApprovedAtRejectedAtToOauthApplications approved_at:datetime rejected_at:datetime`

Edit the file to reflect the correct table.

Keeping in mind that Ruby lets you modify a class from anywhere... In an initializer (or similar); from https://github.com/doorkeeper-gem/doorkeeper/issues/153:

```
doorkeeper_extend_dir = File.join(Rails.root, "app", "models", "doorkeeper")
Dir.glob("#{doorkeeper_extend_dir}/*.rb").each { |f| require(f) }

# app/models/doorkeeper/application.rb
module Doorkeeper
  class Application < ActiveRecord::Base
    def approved?
      approved_at?
    end

    def rejected?
      rejected_at?
    end

    def approve!
      update_column(:approved_at, DateTime.now)
    end  

    def reject!
      update_column(:rejected_at, DateTime.now)
    end
  end
end
```